# RowSums conditional on value

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements

I'm rather new to r and have a question that seems pretty straight-forward.
I want to do rowSums but to only include in the sum values within a specific range (e.g., higher than 0).

e.g. - with the last column being the requested sum

```
  col1  col2  col3  col4 totyearly
1   -5     3     4    NA      7
2    1     40   -17   -3     41
3   NA     NA    -2   -5      0
4   NA     1      1    1      3
```

What I currently have is:

```
df$totyearly <- rowSums(df[, 1:4], na.rm=TRUE)
```

How do I add the condition re positive values?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `replace` to replace the values less than 0 to 0 and then take `rowSums`.

```
df$totyearly <- rowSums(replace(df, df < 0, 0), na.rm = TRUE)
df

#  col1 col2 col3 col4 totyearly
#1   -5    3    4   NA         7
#2    1   40  -17   -3        41
#3   NA   NA   -2   -5         0
#4   NA    1    1    1         3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own custom sum function and `apply` it to each row:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
  col1  col2  col3  col4 totyearly
  1   -5     3     4    NA      7
  2    1     40   -17   -3     41
  3   NA     NA    -2   -5      0
  4   NA     1      1    1      3",
header = TRUE)

#define custom sum function 
sum.pos <- function(x) sum(x[x > 0], na.rm = TRUE)

#apply it to each row
df$totyearly <- apply(df[ , 1:4], 1, sum.pos)

#or equivalently
df$totyearly <- apply(df[ , 1:4], 1, function(x) sum(x[x > 0], na.rm  = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by a logical check and then sum:

```
rowSums(df * (df >= 0), na.rm=TRUE)
# 1  2  3  4 
# 7 41  0  3
```